# Is is possible to zoom beyond the limits in Internet Explorer?

Tags: browser, internet-explorer, zoom, svg

Im using IE to view a large svg file and would like to see the whole image. However IE has a limit of 10% on zooming out, and at that level its still too close to see whole image. Is it possible to zoom out beyond that limit somehow?

Comment: Since I couldnt figure out the answer to the question about internet explorer I found an extension to chrome called SVG Navigator which does the job nicely.